# Count number of occurrences of certain values across columns based on values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

I have a large dataframe in R where I have Names (which repeat themselves) in the first column and then several columns with different character values. The dataframe is this:

```
Names <- c("Benjamin Blue", "Benjamin Blue", "Benjamin Blue", "Sarah Red", "Sarah Red", "Mark Black", "Mark Black", "Mark Black", "Leonie White")
c1 <- c("Health", "Health", "Infrastructure", "Traffic", "Security", "Security", "Security", "Social", "" )
c2 <- c("Social", "", "Traffic", "", "Traffic", "Energy", "Health", "Social", "Security")
c3 <- c("", "", "Infrastructure", "Energy", "Energy", "", "Health", "Securtiy", "Social")
df_test <- data.frame(Names, c1, c2, c3)
df_test
```

How can I count for all individuals (`Benjamin Blue`, `Sarah Red`, `Mark Black`, and `Leonie White`) how many times the topics `Traffic`, `Social`, and `Health` were named across columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

My results should be this:

```
Names_result <- c("Benjamin Blue", "Sarah Red", "Mark Black", "Leonie White")
Traffic <- c(1, 2, 0, 0)
Social <- c(1, 0, 2, 1)
Health <- c(2, 0, 2, 0)
```

I have tried the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df_test %>%
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(Traffic = sum(na.omit(c_across(c1:c3)) == "Social"),
       Traffic = ifelse(all(is.na(c_across(c1:c3))), NA, Traffic))

df_test %>% 
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(Social = sum(na.omit(c_across(c1:c3)) == "Social"),
       Social = ifelse(all(is.na(c_across(c1:c3))), NA, Social))

df_test %>% 
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(Health = sum(na.omit(c_across(c1:c3)) == "Health"),
       Health = ifelse(all(is.na(c_across(c1:c3))), NA, Health))
```

But this doesn't add up the values of each individual in one row and doesn't results in one dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first reshape from "wide" to "long" format, `filter` to only include the relevant items, then `pivot_wider` to reshape back to "wide" format.

We can use `values_fn = length` to "count" the occurrence of each item, and `values_fill = 0` to fill missing items with 0 in `pivot_wider`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_test %>% pivot_longer(-Names, names_to = NULL, values_to = "value") %>% 
  filter(value %in% c("Traffic", "Social", "Health")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Names         Health Social Traffic
  <chr>          <int>  <int>   <int>
1 Benjamin Blue      2      1       1
2 Sarah Red          0      0       2
3 Mark Black         2      2       0
4 Leonie White       0      1       0
```

Comment: Many thanks, it worked and helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it using `pivot_longer`, `count` and `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df_test %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c1:c3) %>% 
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  count(Names, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   Names         Health Infrastructure Social Traffic Security Energy Securtiy
#>   <chr>          <int>          <int>  <int>   <int>    <int>  <int>    <int>
#> 1 Benjamin Blue      2              2      1       1        0      0        0
#> 2 Leonie White       0              0      1       0        1      0        0
#> 3 Mark Black         2              0      2       0        2      1        1
#> 4 Sarah Red          0              0      0       2        1      2        0
```

Another way is to use `dplyover::over`. Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer and the package is not on CRAN.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df_test %>% 
  group_by(Names) %>% 
  summarise(over(c("Traffic", "Social", "Health"),
                 ~ sum(unlist(pick(c1:c3)) %in% .x)))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   Names         Traffic Social Health
#>   <chr>           <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 Benjamin Blue       1      1      2
#> 2 Leonie White        0      1      0
#> 3 Mark Black          0      2      2
#> 4 Sarah Red           2      0      0
```

Data from OP

```r
Names <- c("Benjamin Blue", "Benjamin Blue", "Benjamin Blue", "Sarah Red", "Sarah Red", "Mark Black", "Mark Black", "Mark Black", "Leonie White")
c1 <- c("Health", "Health", "Infrastructure", "Traffic", "Security", "Security", "Security", "Social", "" )
c2 <- c("Social", "", "Traffic", "", "Traffic", "Energy", "Health", "Social", "Security")
c3 <- c("", "", "Infrastructure", "Energy", "Energy", "", "Health", "Securtiy", "Social")
df_test<- data.frame(Names, c1, c2, c3)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution:

```r
cbind(df_test[1], stack(df_test, -1))[1:2] |>
  table() |>
  as.data.frame.matrix() |>
  subset(select = c(Traffic, Social, Health))

#               Traffic Social Health
# Benjamin Blue       1      1      2
# Leonie White        0      1      0
# Mark Black          0      2      2
# Sarah Red           2      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

**`data.table` solution**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_test)

choices <- c("Traffic", "Social", "Health")

dcast(df_test[, .(topic = unlist(.SD[, c1:c3])), Names][topic %in% choices, ], Names ~ topic, fun.aggregate = length)
```

or

```
dcast(melt(df_test, id = "Names")[value %in% choices], Names ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
```

**results**

```
           Names Health Social Traffic
1: Benjamin Blue      2      1       1
2:  Leonie White      0      1       0
3:    Mark Black      2      2       0
4:     Sarah Red      0      0       2
```